# How many individual bags are picked from when picking balls at random?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Assume that we have 100 balls, each identified by a number of 1 to 100. The balls are distributed equally in 10 bags, so we have 10 balls in each of the 10 bags. We know which balls are in which bag.

Now, 10 random numbers are choosen and we pick those from the bags. On average, from how many individual bags to we have to pick?

Keep in mind that we know where each ball is located, so no guessing is involved.

It seems like it doesn't matter if the balls are distributed randomly or not, so I didn't specify this.

**Here's what I got so far:**

When picking once:
We will always have to pick from one bag. The answer is $1$.

When picking twice:
We will always have the first bag to pick from. Additionally, the second pick will be from a new bag in 9 out of 10 cases, which means in those cases we will have picked from a second bag.
That means, on average when picking twice we will have to pick from the following number of bags.

$$\frac{1+(9*2)}{10} = 1.9$$

I think this is correct, but I don't the general way of solving this. In my real-world problem I have variable values for all variables (number of balls, number of bags, number of picks).

Comment: "...in which box."  Huh?  Where did a *box* come from?

Comment: Sorry, mixed boxes and bags. I edited the question.

Comment: @BrianTung I'm unsure whether I have actually posed the following question to you, before; if I have, please ignore it.  Do you know of any online reference (e.g. pdf or website) that provides a proof of the *Linearity of Expectation*?

Comment: Thanks @BrianTung! I knew there was something weird with my example. The number of balls has no impact on this problem at all.

Comment: @plunz: It does, actually.  I just realized I misinterpreted the problem as having selected ten numbers *with replacement*.  Without replacement, the probability for each bag being avoided is actually $\frac{C(90, 10)}{C(100, 10)}$.  The rest of the analysis proceeds without modification.

Comment: @user2661923: Will this do? https://brilliant.org/wiki/linearity-of-expectation/

Comment: @plunz: Otherwise, we have an obvious problem if we choose, say, $91$ numbers instead of $10$, for by the pigeonhole principle, the probability of avoiding any bag is $0$, while the expression $(9/10)^{91}$ gives a very small number, but not literally $0$.

Comment: Let me write this out in an answer, and then I can delete my erroneous comment.

Comment: @BrianTung +1: Wow, thanks.  I had previously skimmed that exact article but **overlooked** its *concealed* proof.  Still, it's somewhat dangerous for someone like me to apply the theorem.  Given my lack of intuition/experience here, it would be too easy for me to **misapply** the theorem.  Unfortunately, now that I've seen the *proof*, the only thing left is for me to study the proof more closely and then work thru all of the examples, thereby **stretching my intuition**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One relatively straightforward way to solve this problem is to make use of the principle of [linearity of expectation](https://dlsun.github.io/probability/linearity.html).  That is, the expected value of a sum, is the sum of the individual expected values.  The additional "trick," if one wishes to call it that, is to recognize that the probability of a trial being successful can be interpreted as the expected number of successes in that trial.

Suppose we have $b$ bags, each with $n$ numbers in it (so there are $bn$ distinct numbers altogether).  We select $k$ numbers.  What is the probability that at least one of the numbers is in the first bag?  It is one minus the probability that *none* of the numbers is in the first bag.  Assuming that all selections of $k$ numbers are equally likely, the probability of avoiding the first bag altogether is

$$
P(\text{no number in first bag}) = \frac{\binom{(b-1)n}{k}}{\binom{bn}{k}}
$$

Therefore,

$$
P(\text{at least one number in first bag}) = 1 - \frac{\binom{(b-1)n}{k}}{\binom{bn}{k}}
$$

As alluded to above, we observe that we can interpret this as

$$
E(\text{number of first bags containing a selected number}) \equiv
P(\text{at least one number in first bag})
$$

This is just an example of the basic principle that the expected number of successes of a single Bernoulli trial is equal to the probability of success.

Now, each bag has an equal probability of containing a selected number (equivalently, each bag has an equal expected number of successes), and the principle of linearity of expectation tells us that the expected number of bags containing at least one selected number is equal to the sum of the individual expected values.  That is, finally,

$$
E(\text{number of bags containing selected numbers})
    = b\left[ 1 - \frac{\binom{(b-1)n}{k}}{\binom{bn}{k}} \right]
$$

This expression is only applicable where $k \leq (b-1)n$, for otherwise, *all* of the bags must contain a selected number.  For the case in your problem, where $b = n = k = 10$, that condition is satisfied, and we have

$$
E(\text{number of bags containing selected numbers})
    = 10\left[ 1 - \frac{\binom{90}{10}}{\binom{100}{10}} \right]
    \approx 6.69524
$$

If we go by what I mistakenly said in the comments (which effectively assumes that the numbers are chosen with replacement), then the expected value is instead about $6.51322$.